# Battery stopped charging: How to turn off Battery Charging Indicator?

Tags: power-management, lenovo, indicator, battery

My Laptop (Lenovo Flex 3, Ubuntu 17.04) just stopped charging the battery.
I still powers up with AC adaptor, but doesn't hold the a charge.
The battery indicator has gone crazy.
It keeps flashing "Battery Critical, 0% charge remaining" and then shows battery as charging. This happens every second and is maddening.

I still don't know why the battery isn't charging, the battery was healthy just yesterday. The AC adapter seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Please keep in mind that common laptop batteries can pose a fire hazard if damaged.** Spontaneous degradation of battery capacity is a possible sign of such damage.

First, unplug the battery while the laptop is turned off and look for signs of obstruction of the contacts. Also visually inspect for signs of heat damage (any molten plastic).

Boot and *enter BIOS* while AC and battery is connected. While in BIOS, unplug AC and see what happens.

1. If the Laptop runs on battery for prolonged times in BIOS, unlike it did when running Ubuntu, you are dealing with a software issue worth investigating.
2. If not, get a new battery and properly dispose of the old one.